# Order items in a listbox in tkinter by an entity value

Tags: python, algorithm, tkinter, listbox, records

I have a leaderboard containing information on some scouts. The structure of this information is as follows: `ID,forname,surname,points`. This information is stored in a file, but isn't in order within the file. I don't want to change this.

I'd like it so that upon updating the listbox (when i call the `calcPoints()` function), it orders the scouts by the points entity within their record, from largest points to smallest points. Below is the code for my `calcPoints()` method.

Thanks

```
def _calcPoints():
        mainWin._leaderboard.delete(0,END)
        with open(tempFileName,'a') as ft:
            for sc in self._Scouts:
                sc._addPoints(-int(sc._getPoints()))
                with open(badgeFile,"r") as fb:
                    lines = fb.readlines()
                    for line in lines:
                        if sc._getID() == line.split(":")[0]:
                            badge = ((line.split(':')[1]).split(',')[0])
                            if badge == "Core":
                                sc._addPoints(5)
                            elif badge == 'Activity':
                                sc._addPoints(1)
                            elif badge == 'Challenge':
                                sc._addPoints(3)
                            elif badge == 'Activity Pack':
                                sc._addPoints(5)
                ft.write(sc.getInfo() + "\n")
        os.remove(leadFile)
        with open(leadFile,"a") as f:
            with open(tempFileName,"r") as ft:
                lines = ft.readlines()
                for line in lines:
                    f.write(line)
        os.remove(tempFileName)
        mainWin.addScoutsLeaderboard()
        return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call sorted, sorting by the last element in each line which is the `points`, using `reverse=True` will sort from high to low:

```
lines = sorted(fb,key=lambda x: float(x.rsplit(":",1)[1]),reverse=True)
```

Not sure which file the data is in so your file object and delimiter should match your actual file, also if you have a header you will need to add `header = next(fb)`.

If you are using the values individually you might find the csv module a better fit:

```
import csv
with open(badgeFile,"r") as fb:
    r = csv.reader(fb,delimiter=":")
    lines = sorted(r, key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True)
    for fid,fname,sname,pnts in lines:
```

On a side note, you only need to call `.readlines()` when you actually need a list, if not you can just iterate over the file object.